# How to sum parent field in SSRS report?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

My table looks like the following structure.

I joined two table in one dataset and put a group in table which caused many duplicate fields of Id and Amount1 in dataset. When I tried to use `[sum(Amount1)]` on the last line, it would give me a wrong answer.

How to get the right one `a1+a2+a3`?

```
Id   Amount1 Amount2
--------------------
1    a1      b1
             b2
             b3
--------------------
2    a2      c1
             c2
             c3
--------------------
3    a3      d1
             d2
--------------------
sum a1+a2+a3
```

Comment: Can yo post the structure of your two tables and some sample data. I suspect the issue is with the dataset rather than the report.

Comment: ^I agree. If a1, a2, and a3 are static fields from the same dataset then you should just be able to use the sum function on whatever field a1,a2, and a3. If you have 3 dataset then you can use the lookup function to grab the 2 remaining values